# webstorm: typescript bool vs. boolean

Tags: javascript, ide, typescript

Webstorm does not recognize some typescript types. I changed the compiler to be Microsoft's in order to get better compiler error (had random 'empty string' messages with the first one):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc.exe

Now it gives me better compiler errors.
However the color coding of errors is still incorrect.

For example, though the type **bool** was changed to **boolean** long ago (https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/135) it does not recognize boolean.

Any ideas how to solve that?

I'm downloading Microsoft Studio Express right now but would prefer to stick with WebStorm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webstorm language service currently only works with 0.8.x,

The  typescript language service inside WebStrom does not understand the changes made in 0.9.x, and since the TypeScript language service api changed (for the better imho) from 0.8 to 0.9 its not a drop in replacement.

A new version of WebStorm with these features is on the way though (should be soon).

Comment: I saw there is an EAP with support for 0.9. Would you know what are the consequences of using an EAP?
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+7+EAP

Comment: It expires after 30 days. Sounds like a solid option :)

Comment: whats the difference between someVar:boolean and someVar:Boolean